# Highlight current line and column

Tags: cursor, highlighting

Is there a solution to highlight current line and column where the cursor is now?

I tried [this plugin](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CrosshairHighlighting), but then emacs motion are lagging like hell.

I was able to highlight the line

```
(global-hl-line-mode 1)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `vline`/`crosshairs` is as good as it gets without creating your own minor-mode.  I created my own and am still (after one year) working on making it more efficient.  Mine is so difficult because I want compatibility with `word-wrap`, and I want a single thin ruler line to the left of each character (not a highlighted thick column), and because there is a bug in Emacs for OSX that prevents composing two characters into one.  If you want to write your own, see this related thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744237/emacs-how-to-create-a-vertical-strike-through-effect

Comment: What do you mean by the lagging - when do you see it, and just what do you see? Can you provide a recipe (from `emacs -Q`) to reproduce it? Do you have `visual-line-mode` turned on, for example? I see absolutely no lag with [crosshairs highlighting](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CrosshairHighlighting), so I suspect that you are doing something particular.

Comment: @Drew Yes, I use visual-line mode. It lags when I start scrolling a long buffer without releasing the motion key.

Comment: @lawlist Do you have any code available?

Comment: I see. I don't (and won't) use `visual-line-mode`, so I guess I can't help here; sorry. There might be a simple fix (dunno), but someone who uses `visual-ine-mode` (and is motivated) will need to debug it and suggest a fix (probably for `vline.el`, I'm guessing).

Comment: You are duplicating your posts (several, now) on both this site and StackOverflow. **Please don't do that.** Please choose one or the other site.

Comment: I am using `xpm` images for every character on the US keyboard and a few characters that are not -- e.g., form-feed, which I display as a fancy cursive capital letter `F`.  I use a modification of some of Drews functions from his color libraries to examine the foreground/background of every point the ruler touches, and the color of the xpm image at each location is displayed based on the color underneath -- i.e., the xpm have 8 or 10 possible areas of color shading, and the colors are determined at each point based on what is underneath.  I chose 18 point size courier font courier . . .

Comment: I spent a couple of days with a magnifying glass adjusting/composing the characters (i.e., each pixel) for the various letters/symbols.  The line changes colors -- even numbered column is yellow; odd numbered column is red; beyond the fill-column on the first line is green; on the second wrapped line to the end of the line is bluish; the far right hand edge of the window is cyan; the horizontal line from wrap-edge to right window edge is maroon.  It is from `window-start` to `window-end`, and includes line numbers.  It is so highly customized, that it is not practical for the public to use.

Comment: @Drew -- As to the slow-down, it is due to the `vertical-motion` that is so costly with `vline.el`, and secondly moving around the buffer -- e.g., `move-to-column`.  Tab-widths and character widths complicate things.  I was able to achieve speed gains by one vertical-motion pass through the buffer from `window-start` to `window-end` to  gather an 18-element list at each stop [not doing anything in particular with the buffer, just the details -- e.g., beginning of visual line, end of visual line, point/char at/before/after target column, line number, etc.].  That list is then mapcar-ed. . .

Comment: @lawlist: As a guess, I interpret what you say about the slowdown as a statement that *`visual-line-mode`* (not `vline.el`) is costly wrt `vertical-motion` and moving around the buffer (e.g. `move-to-column`). Isn't that correct - that `vline` doesn't do anything special or inefficient wrt these things, but it is `visual-line-mode` that does not work well with them? The aim here is to use *columns* even in the presence of very *long lines* and code that is built to handle such long lines. My (wild) guess is that that is the problem: `visual-line-modes` does not play well with columns.

Comment: @Drew -- `vline.el` does not contain the code / mathematical computations needed to handle `word-wrap`ed lines -- that library essentially only supports `word-wrap nil`.  It could be made *a little* more efficient by gathering the data into a list before applying the overlays.  `vertical-motion` by its very nature during the redisplay process is time-costly.  I essentially run `vertical-motion` once per screen line from `window-start` to `window-end`, and then about 3 other times to calculate some related values.

Comment: @Drew -- my guess is that `vertical-motion` / `redisplay` work harder when `word-wrap` is `t`.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can give [`xhair.el`](https://github.com/Boruch-Baum/emacs-xhair) package a try:

> This package simultaneously applies vline-mode and hl-line-mode, with
> tweaks, to present POINT in highlighted cross-hairs, reporting the
> value of POINT as a message in the echo area.